# Calling function of Csharp Application using a injected dll

Tags: c#, c++, function, dll

I want call the ConsoleAppTwo.Program::PrintMessage the application...
i create a csharp test software with a function to call me:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppTwo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void PrintMessage(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad0)
                {
                    PrintMessage("[Whatever string]");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i use the IDA pro to found the functions:
[IDA PRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVYJw.png)

after i use the cheat engine and add the 'address' "ConsoleAppTwo.Program::PrintMessage" and get the address pointer and i create the dll:

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "main.h">

using namespace std;

typedef void(__cdecl *_FuncA)(string str);

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) {
    _FuncA func = (_FuncA)(0x3504F0);

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_HOME))
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) & 1)
        {
            func("What is your name");
        }

        Sleep(10);
    }

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE) param, 0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(0, 0, MainThread, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0, 0);
    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and after i inject the dll in software and the code not work..., i get the output error: "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Comment: Any error output? And btw what exactly is result you expect?

Comment: i want call the function "ConsoleAppTwo.Program::PrintMessage", the output error is "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Comment: Please update your post to include the error and expected result

Comment: A C++ `std::string` and a C# `System.String` alias `string` are two completely different datatypes.

Comment: I replace the std :: string to System.String, the problem is that the method is called but that variable is not shown, show in console a empty line.